# What happens if i do not set an expiration for cache

Tags: apache2, browser-cache

I am testing my page on google pagespeed insights and it comes back with:
*Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network*.

My assumption was that if i did not set an expiry, my files would never expire. Is that incorrect?

All the articles i have seen so far talk about how to set expirations but they do not explain what happens if i do not set one.

Does anyone actually know what happens? Does the browser re-request the files every single time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser will guess cacheable resource freshness using certain heuristics.

Relevant excerpt from [RFC 7234 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.2):

> **4.2.2.  Calculating Heuristic Freshness**

> Since origin servers do not always provide explicit expiration times,
> a cache MAY assign a heuristic expiration time when an explicit time
> is not specified, employing algorithms that use other header field
> values (such as the Last-Modified time) to estimate a plausible
> expiration time.  This specification does not provide specific
> algorithms, but does impose worst-case constraints on their results.

For more information check [The State of Browser Caching, Revisited](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2017/03/16/browser-caching) article by Mark Nottingham.